# Labeling in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, labels

Now I have Figure 1 from the below code. I want to get Figure 2 (adding labels). How to add these things in tikz?

Figure 1

[image: Figure 1]

Figure 2

[image: Figure 2]

Code for Figure 1

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\def\cdf(#1)(#2)(#3){0.5*(1+(erf((#1-#2)/(#3*sqrt(2)))))}
\DeclareMathOperator{\CDF}{cdf}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,font=\footnotesize]
\begin{axis}[
  ticks=none, 
  axis x line=bottom,
  axis y line=left,
  xlabel={Value of $D$},
  ylabel={Cumulative Distribution Function}]
  \addplot[dashed, domain=-6:1.16]{0.2};
  \addplot[dashed, smooth] coordinates {(1.16,0)(1.16,0.2)};
  \addplot[dashed, smooth] coordinates {(-0.84,0)(-0.84,0.55)};
  \addplot[<->, domain=-0.84:1.16]{0.1};
  \addplot[dashdotted, domain=-6:1.75]{0.4};
  \addplot[dashdotted] coordinates {(1.75,0)(1.75,0.55)};
  \addplot[dashdotted] coordinates {(-0.25,0)(-0.25,0.4)};
  \addplot[<->, domain=-0.25:1.75]{0.3};
  \addplot[<->, domain=-0.84:1.75]{0.5};
  \addplot[smooth,red] gnuplot{\cdf(x)(-2)(1)};
  \addplot[smooth,blue]gnuplot{\cdf(x)(0)(1)};
  \addplot[smooth,orange]gnuplot{\cdf(x)(2)(1)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is quite simple actually, just add node along the required paths:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\def\cdf(#1)(#2)(#3){0.5*(1+(erf((#1-#2)/(#3*sqrt(2)))))}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,font=\footnotesize]
\begin{axis}[
  ticks=none, 
  axis x line=bottom,
  axis y line=left,
  clip=false,
  xlabel={Value of $D$},
  ylabel={Cumulative Distribution Function}]
  \addplot[dashed, domain=-6:1.16]{0.2} node [pos=0,left] {$q$};
  \addplot[dashed, smooth] coordinates {(1.16,0.2)(1.16,0.0)};
  \addplot[dashed, smooth] coordinates {(-0.84,0)(-0.84,0.55)};
  \addplot[<->, domain=-0.84:1.16]{0.1} node [midway, above] {$\Delta_1$};
  \addplot[dashdotted, domain=-6:1.75]{0.4} node [pos=0,left] {$q^\prime$};
  \addplot[dashdotted] coordinates {(1.75,0)(1.75,0.55)};
  \addplot[dashdotted] coordinates {(-0.25,0)(-0.25,0.4)};
  \addplot[<->, domain=-0.25:1.75]{0.3} node [midway, above] {$\Delta_2$};
  \addplot[<->, domain=-0.84:1.75]{0.5} node [midway, above] {$\Delta_3$};
  \addplot[smooth,red] gnuplot{\cdf(x)(-2)(1)};
  \addplot[smooth,blue]gnuplot{\cdf(x)(0)(1)};
  \addplot[smooth,orange]gnuplot{\cdf(x)(2)(1)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And the result:
[image: Graph with labels]

Note the need for `clip=false` to allow nodes on the y-axis to be displayed. Feel free to ask in comments if anything is unclear.